# google analytics multi domain version 5 JS syntax

Tags: javascript

I need to do multi domain tracking. The old version of GA said to include

```
onclick="pageTracker._link(this.href); return false;"
```

in the  tag.  The new code to include in the  tag is

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'https://www.xyz.com/whatever']);
```

can I change the domain to this.href like the old code so that I can do a universl replace?  ie.

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', this.href]);
```

I am not familiar with the [] in the function call.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should work. We do something nearly identical on one of our sites.

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', this.href]); return false;"
```

Don't forget to finish it with the `return false` as in your first example.  Here is a test case that should work the same as GA suggests  - http://jsbin.com/#preview

Documentation here - http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._link

Comment: Thanks.  The [] threw me.  I just realized the [] mean it is sending an array.

Comment: Why do you need to return false; That should override the default browser behavior for the HREF...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Google's API works like that, then yes: that syntax is correct.